# How to intercept the back button on an AndroidTV box not to close the AndroidTV App but behave like the back button on the toolbar

Tags: codenameone, android-tv

An AndroidTV App closes when the remote control's back button is pressed. The user is then returned to the main menu of the AndroidTV box. The back button on the toolbar works perfectly, however I would like the same behaviour when the remote back button is pressed.

Comment: On Codename One just use `myForm.setBackCommand()` and implement the logic you want in the commands actionPerformed method.

Comment: Iv'e added the code to the to the action listener                                                     Media video = MediaManager.createMedia(videoUrl, true, () -> parent.showBack());         However the event gets fired when the button is pressed by a mouse click event and not the back button pressed on the remote control.

Comment: You need to use setBackCommand on the form not on the media component.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be an issue with the amdroid tv devices. For instance I tested using a gica box and it works however a mi box does not work. Mi Box does seem t have software issues according to the reviews.

Comment: We have a mi stick here so I can try and test on it. Please file an issue with a test case that reproduces the problem and we'll try to get to it.